# Odd behavior in Imagick PHP

Tags: php, laravel, imagick

So I have a rather peculiar problem with Imagick in my app. The app uses uper input to create a "pet" that they select the color, breed, etc for. Once the pet is generated, it's hex values are saved to a database and then they can equip items to that pet later on. The demo for this functionality is located [here](http://www.novilar.com/demo)

The issue I am having is there's a second script that updates and re-saves the pet when a user equips and item to it or if the pet ages from a baby to an adult. When I run this script, the pets suddenly appear to be much darker than they were when created as demonstrated below:

[image: Horse at creation][image]

As you can see, the pet was a lot lighter at creation than it was at updating. I believe the problem might lie in `COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY` and `COMPOSITE_OVERLAY` behaving differently when creating as when updating, because the script doesn't vary in steps other than pulling from the database vs. pulling from user input (the values are storing correctly).

I'll be honest, I'm not sure if this is a problem of the creation being too light or the update being too dark. The important thing is it has to stay consistent, people won't want their created pet's color to change on them randomly! In all honesty, it seems the updated script produces colors closer to the hex values you see in the first screenshot, which makes me think the creation is too light somehow.

Pet creation script:

```
use \Imagick;
use File;
use App\DataPet;

class PetGenerator
{
/**
 * Generate pet image
 *
 * @param $species
 * @param $baseHex
 * @param $eyeHex
 * @param $age
 * @param $gender
 * @param $genderHex
 * @param $markings
 * @param $layer1
 * @param $layer2
 * @param $layer3
 * @param $layer4
 *
 * @return Imagick
 */
public function drawPet($species, $baseHex, $eyeHex, $age, $gender, $genderHex, $markings, $layer1, $layer2, $layer3, $layer4)
{
    // Call pet data
    $pet = DataPet::where('name', $species)->first();

    // Instantiate adult image objects
    if ($age == 'adult')
    {
        $base = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/base_color.png");
        $eye = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/eye_color.png");
        $lines = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/lines.png");
        $shading = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/shading.png");
        $lights = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/lights.png");

        // Checks for gendered attribute
        if ($pet->gendered == true )
        {
            if ($gender == $pet->gendered_value)
            {
                $genderBase = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->gendered_attribute . "_color.png");
                $genderLines = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->gendered_attribute . "_lines.png");
                $genderShading = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->gendered_attribute . "_shading.png");
                $genderLights = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->gendered_attribute . "_lights.png");

                // Recolors attribute if recolorable
                if ($pet->gendered_recolor == true)
                {
                    $genderBase->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                    $genderBase->setImageBackgroundColor($genderHex);
                    $genderBase->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Instantiate baby image objects
    else {
        $base = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/base_color.png");
        $eye = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/eye_color.png");
        $lines = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/lines.png");
        $shading = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/shading.png");
        $lights = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/lights.png");
    }

    // Recolors base
    $base->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
    $base->setImageBackgroundColor($baseHex);
    $base->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);

    // Recolors eyes
    $eye->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
    $eye->setImageBackgroundColor($eyeHex);
    $eye->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);

    // Begin composite
    // If extra layers: under markings
    if ($pet->layer_name1)
    {
        if ($pet->layer_pos1 == 1)
        {
            if ($age == 'adult')
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->layer_name1 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/" . $pet->layer_name1 . ".png");
            }

            if ($pet->layer_recolor1 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($layer1);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($pet->layer_name2)
    {
        if ($pet->layer_pos2 == 1)
        {
            if ($age == 'adult')
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->layer_name2 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/" . $pet->layer_name2 . ".png");
            }

            if ($pet->layer_recolor2 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($layer2);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($pet->layer_name3)
    {
        if ($pet->layer_pos3 == 1)
        {
            if ($age == 'adult')
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->layer_name3 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/" . $pet->layer_name3 . ".png");
            }

            if ($pet->layer_recolor3 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($layer3);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($pet->layer_name4)
    {
        if ($pet->layer_pos4 == 1)
        {
            if ($age == 'adult')
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->layer_name4 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/" . $pet->layer_name4 . ".png");
            }

            if ($pet->layer_recolor4 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($layer4);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    // Layer markings
    if ($age == 'adult')
    {
        foreach ($markings as $marking => $color)
        {
            $marking = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/markings/" . $marking . ".png");
            $marking->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
            $marking->setImageBackgroundColor($color);
            $marking->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            $base->compositeImage($marking, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        foreach ($markings as $marking => $color)
        {
            $marking = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/markings/" . $marking . ".png");
            $marking->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
            $marking->setImageBackgroundColor($color);
            $marking->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            $base->compositeImage($marking, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    // If extra layers: over markings
    if ($pet->layer_name1)
    {
        if ($pet->layer_pos1 == 0)
        {
            if ($age == 'adult')
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->layer_name1 . ".png");
            } else
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/" . $pet->layer_name1 . ".png");
            }

            if ($pet->layer_recolor1 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($layer1);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($pet->layer_name2)
    {
        if ($pet->layer_pos2 == 0)
        {
            if ($age == 'adult')
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->layer_name2 . ".png");
            }

            else
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/" . $pet->layer_name2 . ".png");
            }

            if ($pet->layer_recolor2 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($layer2);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($pet->layer_name3)
    {
        if ($pet->layer_pos3 == 0)
        {
            if ($age == 'adult')
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->layer_name3 . ".png");
            }

            else
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/" . $pet->layer_name3 . ".png");
            }

            if ($pet->layer_recolor3 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($layer3);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($pet->layer_name4)
    {
        if ($pet->layer_pos4 == 0)
        {
            if ($age == 'adult')
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/" . $pet->layer_name4 . ".png");
            }

            else
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $species . "/baby/" . $pet->layer_name4 . ".png");
            }

            if ($pet->layer_recolor4 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($layer4);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    // Lion tail tuft
    if ($pet->name == 'lion' && $age == 'adult')
    {
        $tuft = new \Imagick("./img/pets/lion/tailtuft.png");

        $tuft->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
        $tuft->setImageBackgroundColor($genderHex);
        $tuft->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);

        $base->compositeImage($tuft, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
    }

    $base->compositeImage($eye, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
    $base->compositeImage($shading, imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0,0);
    $base->compositeImage($lights, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVERLAY, 0, 0);
    $base->compositeImage($lines, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);

    if (isset($genderBase))
    {
        $base->compositeImage($genderBase, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        $base->compositeImage($genderShading, imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0,0);
        $base->compositeImage($genderLights, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVERLAY, 0, 0);
        $base->compositeImage($genderLines, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0,0);
    }

    // Outputs final result
    return $base;
}

public function savePet($id, $img)
{
    $img->writeImage('/assets/pets/' . $id . '.png');
}
}
```

All the input is fed into the function (with markings condensed into an array).

And here's the update script, it accepts a pet object and an optional item object, which will find and add the desired item to the pet. This will also be expanded to include existing items, if such a thing matters for this problem.

```
use \Imagick;
use File;
use App\DataPet;
use App\Pet;
use App\User;
use App\DataItem;

class UpdatePet
{
public function update($p, $i = NULL)
{
    // Retrieve info
    $pet = Pet::findOrFail($p->id);
    $data = DataPet::where('name', $pet->species)->get()->first();

    if ($i) {
        $item = DataItem::findOrFail($i->id);
    }

    // Create marking array
    $markings = array();

    if ($pet->head_marking != 'none') {
        $markings[$pet->head_marking] = $pet->head_color;
    }
    if ($pet->neck_marking != 'none') {
        $markings[$pet->neck_marking] = $pet->neck_color;
    }
    if ($pet->back_marking != 'none') {
        $markings[$pet->back_marking] = $pet->back_color;
    }
    if ($pet->belly_marking != 'none') {
        $markings[$pet->belly_marking] = $pet->belly_color;
    }
    if ($data->legs) {
        if ($pet->leg_marking != 'none') {
            $markings[$pet->leg_marking] = $pet->leg_color;
        }
    }
    if ($data->ears) {
        if ($pet->ear_marking != 'none') {
            $markings[$pet->ear_marking] = $pet->ear_color;
        }
    }
    if ($data->tail) {
        if ($pet->tail_marking != 'none') {
            $markings[$pet->tail_marking] = $pet->tail_color;
        }
    }
    if ($data->wings) {
        if ($pet->wing_marking != 'none') {
            $markings[$pet->wing_marking] = $pet->wing_color;
        }
    }
    if ($pet->eyes_marking != 'none') {
        $markings[$pet->eyes_marking] = $pet->eyes_color;
    }
    if ($pet->fullbody_marking != 'none') {
        $markings[$pet->fullbody_marking] = $pet->fullbody_color;
    }
    if ($pet->free1_marking != 'none') {
        $markings[$pet->free1_marking] = $pet->free1_color;
    }
    if ($pet->free2_marking != 'none') {
        $markings[$pet->free2_marking] = $pet->free2_color;
    }
    if ($pet->free3_marking != 'none') {
        $markings[$pet->free3_marking] = $pet->free3_color;
    }

    // Instantiate adult image objects
    if ($pet->age >= 10)
    {
        $color = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/base_color.png");
        $eye = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/eye_color.png");
        $lines = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/lines.png");
        $shading = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/shading.png");
        $lights = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/lights.png");

        // Checks for gendered attribute
        if ($data->gendered == true )
        {
            if ($pet->gender == $data->gendered_value)
            {
                $genderBase = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->gendered_attribute . "_color.png");
                $genderLines = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->gendered_attribute . "_lines.png");
                $genderShading = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->gendered_attribute . "_shading.png");
                $genderLights = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->gendered_attribute . "_lights.png");

                // Recolors attribute if recolorable
                if ($pet->gendered_recolor == true)
                {
                    $genderBase->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                    $genderBase->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->gendered_color);
                    $genderBase->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Instantiate baby image objects
    else {
        $color = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/base_color.png");
        $eye = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/eye_color.png");
        $lines = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/lines.png");
        $shading = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/shading.png");
        $lights = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/lights.png");
    }

    // Recolors base
    $color->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
    $color->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->base_color);
    $color->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);

    // Recolors eyes
    $eye->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
    $eye->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->eye_color);
    $eye->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);

    // Create base layer (blank unless scene included)
    if ($i) {
        if ($item->type == 9) {
            $base = new \Imagick("./img/sceneries/scene_" . $item->id . ".png");
            $base->compositeImage($color, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    } else {
        $base = new \Imagick("./img/empty.png");
        $base->compositeImage($color, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
    }

    // Begin composite
    // If extra layers: under markings
    if ($data->layer_name1)
    {
        if ($data->layer_pos1 == 1)
        {
            if ($pet->age >= 10)
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->layer_name1 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/" . $data->layer_name1 . ".png");
            }

            if ($data->layer_recolor1 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->layer1_color);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($data->layer_name2)
    {
        if ($data->layer_pos2 == 1)
        {
            if ($pet->age >= 10)
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->layer_name2 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/" . $data->layer_name2 . ".png");
            }

            if ($data->layer_recolor2 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->layer2_color);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($data->layer_name3)
    {
        if ($data->layer_pos3 == 1)
        {
            if ($pet->age >= 10)
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->layer_name3 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/" . $data->layer_name3 . ".png");
            }

            if ($data->layer_recolor3 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->layer3_color);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($data->layer_name4)
    {
        if ($data->layer_pos4 == 1)
        {
            if ($pet->age >= 10)
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->layer_name4 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/" . $data->layer_name4 . ".png");
            }

            if ($data->layer_recolor4 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->layer4_color);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    // Layer markings
    if ($pet->age >= 10)
    {
        foreach ($markings as $marking => $color)
        {
            $marking = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/markings/" . $marking . ".png");
            $marking->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
            $marking->setImageBackgroundColor($color);
            $marking->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            $base->compositeImage($marking, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        foreach ($markings as $marking => $color)
        {
            $marking = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/markings/" . $marking . ".png");
            $marking->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
            $marking->setImageBackgroundColor($color);
            $marking->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            $base->compositeImage($marking, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    // If extra layers: over markings
            if ($data->layer_name1)
    {
        if ($data->layer_pos1 == 0)
        {
            if ($pet->age >= 10)
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->layer_name1 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/" . $data->layer_name1 . ".png");
            }

            if ($data->layer_recolor1 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->layer1_color);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($data->layer_name2)
    {
        if ($data->layer_pos2 == 0)
        {
            if ($pet->age >= 10)
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->layer_name2 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/" . $data->layer_name2 . ".png");
            }

            if ($data->layer_recolor2 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->layer2_color);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($data->layer_name3)
    {
        if ($data->layer_pos3 == 0)
        {
            if ($pet->age >= 10)
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->layer_name3 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/" . $data->layer_name3 . ".png");
            }

            if ($data->layer_recolor3 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->layer3_color);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if ($data->layer_name4)
    {
        if ($data->layer_pos4 == 0)
        {
            if ($pet->age >= 10)
            {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/" . $data->layer_name4 . ".png");
            }

            else {
                $layer = new \Imagick("./img/pets/" . $pet->species . "/baby/" . $data->layer_name4 . ".png");
            }

            if ($data->layer_recolor4 == 1)
            {
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
                $layer->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->layer4_color);
                $layer->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
            }

            $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    // Lion tail tuft
    if ($pet->species == 'lion' && $pet->age >= 10)
    {
        $tuft = new \Imagick("./img/pets/lion/tailtuft.png");

        $tuft->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
        $tuft->setImageBackgroundColor($pet->gendered_color);
        $tuft->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);

        $base->compositeImage($tuft, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
    }

    $base->compositeImage($eye, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
    $base->compositeImage($shading, imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0,0);
    $base->compositeImage($lights, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVERLAY, 0, 0);
    $base->compositeImage($lines, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);

    if (isset($genderBase))
    {
        $base->compositeImage($genderBase, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        $base->compositeImage($genderShading, imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0,0);
        $base->compositeImage($genderLights, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVERLAY, 0, 0);
        $base->compositeImage($genderLines, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0,0);
    }

    // Attaches Skin, if any
    if ($i) {
        if ($item->type == 8) {
            $skin = new \Imagick("./img/assets/skins/skin_" . $item->id . ".png");
            $base->compositeImage($skin, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    // Outputs final result
    $base->writeImage('./img/assets/pets/' . $pet->id . '.png');
    return true;
}
}
```

On an unrelated note, is there a way to make it so the user won't need to clear their cache upon every update to see the changes in the image? As it stands now, you have to ctrl+f5 every time.

Comment: To force browsers reload the generated image, you can try to add a unique token to the query string, like this: `<img src="/path/to/image.png?tkn=<?php echo uniqid(); ?>" />` So each time an image is generated, a browser will receive a unique URL and will load it from there.

Comment: i'm having trouble with `imagemagick` as well. ever since the latest package update

Comment: Great idea! Thank you.

Comment: Try that and let us know if that helps

Comment: @dave That worked like a charm! Perfect solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding this:

```
-colorspace sRGB
```

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/36597

Comment: While this specifically didn't answer my problem, you def pushed me in the right direction. Turns out the creation script was running as RGB and the updater running as sRGB. Set both to sRGB using `$base->setImageColorSpace(imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);` and it's running just fine now!